What is the intended purpose of declaring a class without a body?
In C# now (I'm not certain when this was added to the spec) we can declare a class without a body:
public class MyClass;

If I create an instance, though, I can't do anything with it.

I thought it might have something to do with primary constructors (added in C# 12), so I tried this:
public class MyClass(int myArg);

But then I get a warning on the parameter indicating that it's not used anywhere.  I'm just wondering what the purpose of the body-less class is.

I would assume its just to have same syntax as record?!?

But why?  To what end, if it can't be used for anything (that I can figure out, at least).

This was always legal: public class MyClass {}, so at some point the default empty brackets were made optional. As for why you'd do it, not really any point in and of itself, other than as you found, implementing a generic base class.

You save one character. class MyClass {} was really too verbose.

Why? Well, why not?

Well, I figured out one use case after I thought about it a little more.  It allows for a very succinct syntax -- yes, using primary constructors -- for creating concrete classes deriving from generics, for example:
public abstract class MyBaseClass<TThing>
{
    protected MyBaseClass(TThing thing)
    {
        Thing = thing;
    }

    public TThing Thing { get; }
}

public class MyClass(int num) : MyBaseClass<int>(num);


"... for creating concrete classes". Or 'less generic' classes:
public abstract class MyBaseClass<TThing, TFoo> { ... } . . .
public class MyClass(int num) : MyBaseClass<int, TFoo>(num);

I thought it might have something to do with primary constructors
Yes, it does, check out the syntax section of the Primary constructors feature spec. Class declaration now can have a parameter_list which is optional (denoted with ?):

Class and struct declarations are augmented to allow a parameter list on the type name, an argument list on the base class, and a body consisting of just a ;:
class_declaration
  : attributes? class_modifier* 'partial'? class_designator identifier type_parameter_list?
      parameter_list? class_base? type_parameter_constraints_clause* class_body
  ;


But then I get a warning on the parameter indicating that it's not used anywhere.
Because you don't, unlike the records primary ctors do not result in properties generated by default.
I'm just wondering what the purpose of the body-less class is.
Creating a bodyless class was always possible, now it's just has a shorter syntax. One of the reasons why you can want the bodyless class is when you combine it with inheritance:
public abstract class Distance(double dx, double dy)
{
    public override string ToString() => $"{dx}:{dy}"; // some example behavior
}

public class ConcreteDistance(double dx, double dy) : Distance(dx, dy);

Other potential usages:

To pair with some source generation, when the actual body will be generated by some tooling (potentially based on some attributes for example).
"Marker" base class (though arguably interface would be sufficient in that case).


Could you please share an example of the declaration using the parameter_list?  I'm having trouble following the syntax they use in those specs.

@rory.ap (double dx, double dy) is a parameter list (at least to my understanding).

ah, I see, so it's just describing the primary constructor parameter list.  Got it.

@rory.ap yes, updated the link description to make it more clear.
